# setenv variable with spaces in launchd.conf?

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm a Linux user that just recently got a mac. I'm trying to set up my IDE and found out that Macs don't use .bashrc / .bash_profile / etc. for GUI apps. So, if you have a GUI app that needs an environment variable, you're apparently supposed to do it in /etc/launchd.conf

The thing is, this file uses csh style setenv syntax ("setenv key value" instead of "export key='value'") so now that I have a variable that has a space in it, I don't know what to do. Nothing is working. This is what I've tried to test it:

```
setenv MAVEN_OPTS "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
setenv MAVEN_OPTS1 '-Xms512m -Xmx1024m'
setenv MAVEN_OPTS2 (-Xms512m -Xmx1024m)
setenv MAVEN_OPTS3=(-Xms512m -Xmx1024m)
setenv MAVEN_OPTS4 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
setenv MAVEN_OPTS5 -Xms512m
setenv MAVEN_OPTS6 "$MAVEN_OPTS5 -Xmx1024"
setenv MAVEN_OPTS7 $MAVEN_OPTS5 -Xmx1024
setenv MAVEN_OPTS8 /just/checking
setenv MAVEN_OPTS9="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
setenv MAVEN_OPTS10='-Xms512m -Xmx1024m'
setenv MAVEN_OPTS11='-Xms512m\ -Xmx1024m'
setenv MAVEN_OPTS12 '-Xms512m\ -Xmx1024m'
setenv MAVEN_OPTS13 "-Xms512m\ -Xmx1024m"
setenv MAVEN_OPTS14 -Xms512m\ -Xmx1024m
```

After a reboot only var #5 and #8 survive. (The ones with no spaces.) None of the rest are in my environment.

Comment: have you figured out how to have it working? I'm having the same problem. I've also noticed that concat Vars doesn't work. I can't specify: setenv MV 1    setenv MV12 $MV/2

Comment: No, sorry. Hopefully some kind, well-informed soul will drop in one day and let us know the solution. ;)

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. those env vars problems, every time same thing different problem :S

Comment: Hav you tried Serge's suggestion? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using launchd instead (create plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/java.props.plist):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>java.props</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>launchctl</string>
        <string>setenv</string>
        <string>JAVA_OPTS</string>
        <string>-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This will run once and set your environment up. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks a million! I have been looking for a solution for this all day. This is the only things that works globally.

Comment: How about more than one environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to `/etc/launchd.conf` (create if it doesn't exist)

`setenv MY_VARIABLE My\ value\ with\ spaces`

Note that this will only have an effect after rebooting.

To use the new value without having to reboot, **additionally** run the command in the terminal

`launchctl setenv MY_VARIABLE My\ value\ with\ spaces`

as patrikha suggested.

Note that this will only have an effect for applications started after running the command. Manipulating `/etc/launchd.conf` is still necessary to keep the change after rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work as in a c-shell because /etc/launchd.conf is nothing but a sequence of special commands for launchctl. See the launchctl man page for a reference on what works in /etc/launchd.conf

Sadly, this still won't help you to solve this problem, but I hope it will clarify the context a little. To me this problem is a shortcoming in Apple's launchctl/launchd tools. I have a hard time working around it myself.

Answer (score 2):

On 10.8.2 the following command works fine:

```
$ launchctl setenv MY_VARIABLE My\ value\ with\ spaces
```

Verify with:

```
$ launchctl getenv MY_VARIABLE
My value with spaces
```

Comment: `launchctl` in Terminal and `launchd.conf` are completely unrelated. `bash` parses backslashes, `launchd.conf` does not.

Answer (score 1):

In 10.13.2, this works for me:

launchctl setenv MY_VARIABLE 'My value with spaces'

But to be specific, I'm using Script Editor to create an app (~/StartupEnvVars.app) containing lines like this:

do shell script "launchctl setenv MY_VARIABLE 'My value with spaces'"

Then, in Settings|Users|Login Items I add this app as a startup item.

It works, with this caveat: if I have Terminal and my R app running when I log out, and choose to reopen windows on logging back in, after those apps auto load when I log in, they DO NOT see the environment variables set by StartupEnvVars.app.  But, if I close those apps and reopen them, then they see the environment variables.

If it were Terminal only, I'd use .bash_profile, but I want to set env vars for use in R also.  I think there have been about 5 ways to set global env vars in OSX since I started using it.  Each major new version has a new way of doing it.  Annoying.