# Ensuring MAVEN_HOME is set correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

A Java and Maven noob here:

Using OSX 10.8

And Installed Maven with HomeBrew

1- If I say `which mvn` I will get this: `/usr/local/bin/mvn`

2- If I say `echo $MAVEN_HOME`  I will get nothing back.

3- If I go to my Maven Installation on EClipse it will look like this:

[image]

4- If I go to Maven settings in IntelliJ, it will look like this:  So far I have been able to run Maven goals with IntelliJ.

[image]

Ok That's all I have.  Can you please take a look and see what are the inconsistencies I am having and what things to fix to set this correctly everywhere?

Comment: edit `~\.profile` to add an `export` statement. [This](http://javapapo.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/setup-javahome-mavenhome-anthome-in.html) ought to help.

Comment: I don't have that. Instead I have a bash_profile

Comment: I am mostly interested to see according to the settings I already have and their outputs, what areas seem wrong and how to fix those.

Comment: Create it, it will be used.

Comment: Ok will do, but then what happens to the settings I already have for IntelliJ and EClipse?  what changes should I make for them?

Comment: What is the problem ? Your settings are fine as long as you are using Maven in eclipse . If you are running it from console then you need to set Maven_Home for console to identify Maven installation

Comment: @AvinashSingh : I don't know what is the problem. I don't even know is there any problem with what I already have and posted? For example why my echo maven_home returned blank? or even echo java_home returned blank ? but still my IntelliJ worked just fine and was able to run a maven package goal. I am simply asking someone take a look at the setting I have posted and tell me what things are wrong or missing and how to add them .

Comment: @DarkNightFan Your settings are fine . You don't have to set M2_HOME or M3_HOME when using in eclipse or IntelliJ. You can use `export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven` if you plan on using it from console

Answer (score 1):

Under Mac OS X you should setup your environment variables in `/etc/launchd.conf`. Variables loaded by launchd are available in your shell as well as in GUI applications like Intellij IDEA.

Intellij IDEA will use M2_HOME to find the Maven installation. Edit or create `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
setenv M2_HOME /usr/share/maven
```

Unfortunately to see the effect, you have to reboot your machine. Another shortcoming is, that you cannot use spaces in the file. This means, you cannot set MAVEN_OPTS to [more than one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519292/setenv-variable-with-spaces-in-launchd-conf).