# Maven build failure Mac OS 10

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've just downloaded Maven 3.1.1, placed it under the Spring STS 'springsource' folder then through the STS I created a new Spring MVC project, but I get a lot of errors in this new (almost empty) project pom.xml file, so I right clicked on pom.xml, selected Run As > Maven Clean then Run As > Maven install, but I always get the BUILD FAILURE message as follows:

> Failed to execute goal on project myapp: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.testing.myapp:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
>   The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.springframework:spring-context-jar:3.1.1.RELEASE,
>   org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.1.RELEASE......

After searching the web, I found resources pointing that this problem is due to firewall configuration, but I am 100% sure that I am not behind any firewall, so can someone please guide me and tell me what I am missing here?

My OS is Mac OS 10.8 and I am using STS 3.4.0
The sample application I've build I didn't add any code to it, it was simple Spring MVC application which I've created using STS wizard.

NOTE: When I try to compile pom.xml from command line using the command ( mvn compile ) it works normally

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clean `<YOUR HOME FOLDER>/.m2/` and then try to rebuild. If problem still exists could you please look at build log and post errors from it here?

Comment: I tried cleaning the .m2 folder, then tried to open the project again so it started rebuilding then stopped at 55% giving the following error:  Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Sample01'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Comment: REST OF ERROR: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: Are you working through the proxy or direct internet connection? Do you have `<repositories>` or `<pluginRepositories>` in your pom.xml?

Comment: No proxy at all...just direct internet connection. Where <repositories>? I mean where shall they be located?

Comment: If you have success build when running in console the problem is not in connection. What profile you are running in STS? mvn install?

Comment: in STS, I select pom.xml from the project, right click on it and select Run As > Maven Install, then I get all the errors mentioned before

Answer (score 2):

Check your environment variables. See this question for further help [Ensuring MAVEN_HOME is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709845/ensuring-maven-home-is-set-correctly)

Comment: checked all environment variables (M2_HOME, M2, PATH) which I have placed under my home folder in .bash_profile file and they seem OK, I can type mvn -version in command line and get maven info displayed correctly with Maven home path, java version, java home path...etc

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a maven repository containing `com.testing.myapp:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`? If yes is maven configured to use this repository e.g. in `~/.m2/settings.xml`? It looks like your project needs a dependency which is not public (meaning yours or of your company) and thus needs to be provided from a non-central repository

Comment: When I go to the .m2 folder under my Mac OS home folder, I can't see testing folder under the com folder, so I don't think maven have installed it when i click on maven > install from STS, and as I've mentioned in the question the Maven > Install command return failure with error. I don't have settings.xml under the .m2 folder but I tried adding settings.xml but still it doesn't work

Comment: No, it needs a repository configured in `<repositories><repository>` of either your `pom.xml` or in `settings.xml` to know where to download the dependency from **in order** to add it to `~/.m2/repositories`... Alternatively you can have a multi module build where all the dependencies are compiled at once. Possibly it may also be enough to compile your dependency with `clean install` first if you have it as a source in order for maven to put it into `~/.m2/repositories`, but I am not sure if compilation of the original module that requires it will be able to find it that way

Comment: Well, I would always have an SVN/Git, Jenkins and Nexus at my disposal and can only recommend to install all of those at least locally if you do not have centralized resources. This will greatly improve your productivity in cases like this. Relevant to your question would be in this case Nexus, although other free tools are available for the same purpose as well.

Answer (score 0):

It works now..the problem was that it required JDK while my Mac OS had only JRE. Now it build, install from STS with no problem. Thanks a lot @shoorick for your constructive help and time