# Set an environment variable containing space in MacOS Maverick

Tags: environment-variables, launchd

I try to set a permanent environment variable in MacOS 10.9.5 editing the following file:

```
/etc/launchd.conf
```

Here is the file content:

```
setenv VAR1 "testwithoutspace"
setenv VAR2 "test with space"
```

After reboot, the *VAR1* is set but not the *VAR2*. I can reproduce this problem by using the following command mentioned in the *launchd.conf* comment:

```
grep -E "^setenv" /etc/launchd.conf | xargs
```

If I perform the command directly it works:

```
launchctl setenv VAR2 "test with space"
```

What is happening?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519292/setenv-variable-with-spaces-in-launchd-conf ?

Comment: Did try with back slash?

Comment: @Thomas Yes without success.

Comment: I created a bug #20815988 on https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @farialima It is not a very nice solution but it worked :-)